# On Cartan's remark about interchange of summation and limit

Tags: analysis, sequence-of-function

I am reading Henri Cartan's *Elementary Theory of Analytic Functions of One or Several Complex Variables*. On p.18, he wrote:

> Recall that the limit of a uniformly convergent sequence of *continuous* functions (on a topological space $E$) is continuous. In particular, *the sum of a normally convergent series of continuous functions is continuous*. **An important consequence of this is**:
>
> PROPOSITION 1.2. Suppose that, for each $n$, $\lim_{x\to x_0}u_n(x)$ exists and takes the value $a_n$. Then, if the series $\sum_nu_n$ is normally convergent, the series $\sum_na_n$ is convergent and
> $$\sum_na_n = \lim_{x\to x_0}\left(\sum_nu_n(x)\right)$$
> (changing the order of the summation and the limiting process).

I understand why the proposition is true (a proof under the weaker assumption that $\sum_nu_n$ converges uniformly can be found in theorem 7.11 of "Baby Rudin", and normal convergence implies uniform convergence). What I don't understand, however, is Cartan's remark.

Why is this proposition a consequence of the fact that the sum of a normally convergent series of continuous functions is continuous? The $u_n$s in the proposition are not necessarily continuous. Am I missing something?

Comment: Would the comment hold if we just had continuity at a point?  We may assume without loss of generality that the $u_n$ are continuous at $x_0$

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes, but then it's more like the comment is a consequence of the proposition rather than the other way round.

Comment: I'm not so sure.  The fact that he allows for the domain to be any topological space should allow you to define the topology 
$$\tau = \{A \cup B(x_0,r) : A \subseteq \mathbb{R}\setminus \{x_0\}, r \geq 0\}$$
where $B(x_0,r) = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : |x - x_0| < r\}$ and unless I'm mistaken, the continuous functions from this space to your target space should be exactly those functions that were continuous at $x_0.$ (obviously, it doesn't need to be $\mathbb{R},$ but it should suffice to illustrate the point) -- it's possible I am mistaken, though...

Comment: @BrianMoehring That's clever. Would you please convert your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, let's assume $u_n : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},$ and since the proposition doesn't involve $u_n(x_0)$ at all, we may define, without loss of generality, $u_n(x_0) = a_n$ in order to assume the $u_n$ are continuous at $x_0.$

Since Henri Cartan's remark holds for a general topological space $E,$ we may define $E = (\mathbb{R}, \tau)$ with the topology
$$\tau = \{A \cup B(x_0,r) : A \subseteq \mathbb{R}\setminus\{x_0\}, r \geq 0\} \\ \text{where}\quad B(x_0,r) = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : |x - x_0| < r\}$$
and then note that $u_n : E \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous if and only if $u_n$ is continuous at $x_0$ in the usual topology.

With this choice of $E,$ the remark now implies the proposition.